# Storing time with milliseconds in database

Tags: mysql, best-practices, timestamp

Just a quick question regarding storing "time" in a database. I'm logging the time of users runs which are in the format 00:00:00:00 (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).

I was originally going to store it as `TIME` but then I realised MySQL doesn't support milliseconds in this type.

I will be storing the actual time taken from the users stopwatch, not the time when they ran and finished (this will be calculated before being inserted).

What would be the best field type to use? I was thinking either `double` or `float`, but I'm not sure that would work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I'd use integer types for *duration*

Example: 340,000 milliseconds is 340000 in an unsigned int column.

To me, datetime, time, date etc are for explicit points in time. 340 seconds is meaningless in that context. Having a start `date/time` allows the *duration* to be added of course

Comment: There is a standard SQL `interval` data type for just this purpose. But not all DBMS (and definitely not MySQL) support this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would I need to convert it to a standard format as currently it is in the format 00:00:00:00? Could I set the column to allow that type of format?

Comment: @Elliott: for display, you could. It is just a number otherwise

Comment: Note that your format probably is (or should be for readability) 00:00:00.000  (note the dot instead of colon and 3 digits for milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

If you use MySQL 5.6.4 or later, you can use the `TIME(3)`, `DATETIME(3)` and `TIMESTAMP(3)` column types to store up to 6 fractional digits (replace `3` with the number of fractional digits you need). Fractional part is added to time string after dot; example: `2018-09-08 17:51:04.781`.

[Official reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Comment: Thanks sir, why no one talk about this

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how long you want to measure.  If you won't be recording any times longer than 2^32, or 4294967296 ms than a regular unsigned int is just fine.  That corresponds to about 50 days of clock time, btw.

If you were storing unix time stamps or larger intervals then look at using bigint.  This gives you 8 bytes of space, or the ability to record times as long at 1.84467440737096e+19 ms (which is roughly 500 Million years)